# Vagrant VirtualBox VM is initializing new instead of loading the existing VM after VagrantFile change

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, vagrant

I setup a Vagrant Ubuntu 12.04 box (VirtualBox as the provider) on Windows and it's been working great for the past few months. Yesterday, I added another forwarded port to the VagrantFile and did `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up`. Once I logged in, none of the programs I had installed were there ( `which git` showed nothing ).

I can boot the VM manually through the VirtualBox gui and everything is correct, so I know it's there and working. I tried the solution in [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600566/vagrant-up-is-not-starting-the-vm-in-vagrant-machines-default-virtualbox-id), but `vagrant up` still doesn't start the existing vm.

Here's the VirtualBox Log for my Vagrant VM: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6460060/

Not sure where else to look. Is there a way to force vagrant to load the existing VM?

**Edit:** Here's my VagrantFile as well. It's pretty standard, but I guess it might help. https://gist.github.com/gorrillamcd/7694989

Keep in mind that the machine was working fine until I made a change to my VagrantFile. It's the only thing that changed between functioning and non-functioning.

Comment: do you have a vagrant machine with same name configured elsewhere, Vagrant boxes are not dependent on Vagrantfile path, for eg., if boxname given at config.vm.box = "boxname" is the unique identifier for box internally and you might have used the same name in multiple locations and did the changes there.

Comment: No, I only have one Vagrant machine on my computer (my first to be exact). The box I'm using is `precise32` from the vagrant website. I'll update the question with a bit of information and my VagrantFile.

Answer (score 6):

The link between your working directory (the one with the `Vagrantfile`) and the VirtualBox VM is a file called `id` placed in the following subdirectory:

```
.vagrant\machines\<machine_name>\virtualbox
```

(Usually the `<machine_name>` for a single VM `Vagrantfile` is `default`).

The `id` file contains the UUID of the VirtualBox VM. You should check out the correct UUID using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" showvminfo <VM_NAME> | findstr /B UUID
```

Then you should replace the `id` file with that UUID, and finally run `vagrant up`.

Comment: You can also use `VBoxManage list vms` to easily get a list of VirtualBox's VMs together with their IDs. Also `id` file **must not** contain any white space characters, e.g. new-line character after the UUID.